# VS Solution closes automatically

Tags: visual-studio-2008

When i open the visual studio project, it automatically closes after few seconds.

Comment: All projects? Just one? If the latter, what kind?

Answer (score 2):

I have had a project do something similar. I was able to get it to load by deleting  or renaming the [.suo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165909%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) file. When you restart your solution the file will be recreated.